# Number of specific files in a folder

Tags: javascript, file, server

I just need to know how many files of a specified type (eg. jpg) reside in a server folder.

Something like

```
var numberOfFiles = countFilesInFolder();  //I made up this method
```

Is there a Javascript or an Ajax solution? What Ajax method should I invoke?

//EDIT: I'm not seeking a php/Ajax solution, like outputting and xml and reading it via Javascript.

Comment: You will need server side assistance for this. Issue AJAX request, with server script providing this information.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client, it doesn't know what's on the server. You need to write a server script that does this, and call it using AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar Your statement is incorrect. JavaScript is a programming language and is used in many browser, but it is not restricted to be used on the client. To give a very prominent example, take a look at node.js. It seems like the OP indeed wants to do this from a client, but in general it is of course possible using JS as well.

Comment: @dirkk If he's talking about server-side JS, like node.js, he should tag appropriately. I think it's safe to interpret generic JS questions as being about browser-side JS.

Comment: I'm not referring to node.js. I just need something like and xmlhttpRequest (I think) and an Ajax method to count the files.

Comment: @Barmar The question is even tagged server... However, I am sure you are right about the OP and I appreciate that you think for the OP and you assumption is very reasonable. I only object to your statement "Javascript runs on the client", which is simply not true (and further visitors to the question might be mislead).

Comment: Hmm if you don't want an ajax solution, why are you asking if there is an ajax solution, which is your only option anyway? You need _something_ on the server for the ajax request to talk to, which would have to be a server language like node, asp.net, php etc

Comment: Rhumborl, I mean I don't want a hybrib ajax/php solution. I just need plain javascript/ajax